# ValueError when trying to plot a histogram

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

**Problem Background**

I am trying to plot a histogram to see the distribution of Customer Ages in a bin of size 4. I was initially using a different size of bin, but adjusting the bin this way affected the count or the y-axis of the graph.

Using plt.ylim(min, max) was my way to set the y-axis. To specify the max variable, I tried to count the largest value in the bin which was for ages (25<x<=35).

I keep getting a value error when making the count. Even when I convert the series to an integer using .astype(int), it displays another error.

**Error Message:**
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Please, how do I rectify this?

**Code Snippet**

```
freq, bins, patches = plt.hist(bank_churn_df['Customer_Age'], 
                               label = 'Ages', 
                               bins=4)

plt.ylim(0,bank_churn_df[(bank_churn_df.Customer_Age > 25) & (bank_churn_df.Customer_Age <= 35)].value_counts())
```

Comment: Maybe you could try without calling `plt.ylim()`? Matplotlib calculates the limit automatically. If you want less or more empty space, you can use e.g. `plt.margins(y=0.01)`. If you really want the series, you could use `.max()` to get its maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Note that *ylim* expects 2 arguments: *bottom* and *top*.
Both should be **single** values.

As *bottom* you passed *0*, so far OK, it is a single value.

But the *top* is the result of *value_counts()*, i.e. it is a pandasonic
**Series** of values.

All what I wrote above is however only a marginal remark.

I see such a flaw in your code, that *value_counts* computes how many times
occurs each **individual** value.
But the *top* limit of your *y* axis should be the *max* of how many values
are **in each bin**.

So maybe you should:

- first compute *pd.cut* from your source data,
- then compute *value_counts* from them,
- and finally take *max* of these values.

Another try is to generate your histogram **without** any explicit
call to *ylim*, relying on default values.